# Análisis de datos no normalizados pareados (Wilcoxon vs T-Student) - R

Tags: r

Estoy analizando un conjunto de datos pareados no normalizados y quisiera aplicarles un test estadístico que reafirme algunos parámetros descriptivos de la población. He encontrado el test de ranking signados de *Wilcoxon* (*V, Wilcoxon signed-rank*), pero tengo la impresión de que el test no está siendo clarificador como creí en un comienzo.

Solo para demostrar el ejemplo, tengo las siguientes dos columnas de un dataframe:

```
df <- structure(
    list(
        dist_A = c(
 788.19, 886.03, 766.39, 474.92, 445.6 , 642.67, 743.43, 344.49, 545.98, 767.1,
 343.79, 543.91, 957.16, 998.04, 484.58, 550.69, 344.22, 432.37, 933.5 , 548.62, 960.86,
1046.61, 700.26,1049.46, 308.02, 386.54, 447.75, 445.02, 621.87, 526.16, 369.4 , 716.62,
 662.69, 871.35,1091.77,1161.01, 844.25, 946.43,1017.83,1009.33, 785.61,1015.04,1015.85,
    378, 807.94, 778.71, 590.31, 527.72, 946.12, 762.25
        ),
        dist_O = c(
 648, 894,1005, 691, 472, 501, 475, 395, 533, 900, 266, 200, 594, 955, 200, 728, 272, 272,
1004, 499,1059, 985,1077,1135, 581, 100, 497, 468, 763, 723, 673, 848, 842, 875,1050,1166,
 594, 828, 753, 914, 409, 730, 791, 795,1088,1078, 494, 494, 869, 955
        )
    ),
    .Names = c("dist_A", "dist_O"),
    row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame"
)
```

Donde cada columna tiene un valor de mediana similar:

```
> median(df$dist_A)
[1] 730.025
> median(df$dist_O)
[1] 729
```

Investigando mucho, encontré [en este libro (p.1)](http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/11886/12171343/OnlineTopics/bbs12e_onlinetopic_ch12-8.pdf) algo clarificador: Que el método de *Wilcoxon* para datos pareados no normalizados **tiene como hipótesis nula la equidad de medianas**. En base a esto, ejecuté el test de *Wilcoxon* en *R* (**wilcox.test**) obteniendo lo siguiente:

```
> wilcox.test(df$dist_A, df$dist_O, paired=TRUE, correct = FALSE, alternative = "greater")

    Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  df$dist_A and df$dist_O
V = 653, p-value = 0.4405
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

El resultado lo interpreto como que no hay evidencia suficiente para rechazar la hipótesis nula, que es que la mediana de `dist_A` es menor o igual que la mediana de `dist_O`, esto en base a la hipótesis alternativa propuesta,  `alternative = "greater"`, según [esta documentación para el test](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/2.5.0/doc/html/stats/wilcox.test.html).

**En resumen: Me parece coherente** que el test no pueda aseverar para ambas columnas, de 50 datos cada una y con una mediana similar, el rechazo o no de la hipótesis nula.

---

Explicado lo anterior, mi problema comienza cuando amplío la muestra por sobre los **500 registros**. Siendo más preciso, si le aplico el test a un ***dataframe*** con **1500 datos por columna**, con **medianas similares**, obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
> median(dfs$dist_A)
[1] 1330.13
> median(dfs$dist_O)
[1] 1331.5
> wilcox.test(dfs$dist_A, dfs$dist_O, paired=TRUE, correct = FALSE, alternative = "greater")

    Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  df$dist_A and df$dist_O
V = 298580, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

De donde interpreto que el test entrega con certeza absoluta de que la mediana de `dist_A` es menor o igual a `dist_O`. Eso es, efectivamente, lo que ocurre, pero la diferencia entre ambas medianas es tan poca que el test no me es útil, si yo quisiera darle un margen de tolerancia a la obtención de estas medianas. Se me ocurre que esto sucede por la gran cantidad de muestras, pero no estoy seguro.

***¿Qué requiero o qué busco?*** Quisiera un test, o un ajuste a este mismo, que, aún para muchas mediciones, fuese capaz de entender que con pequeñas diferencias entre las medianas (o medias u otro parámetro si fuese otro test) el ***p-value*** obtenido considere una tolerancia entre ambas mediciones. Es decir, que para una diferencia muy pequeña entre las medianas, el test no tenga la certeza absoluta de rechazar o no la hipótesis nula.

***¿Por qué busco esto?*** Porque los valores testeados son distancias obtenidas por diferentes sistemas de georreferencia, por lo que una pequeña diferencia entre los valores no es significativa.

Finalmente, ¿Puedo aplicar ***T Student*** (**t.test**) de alguna forma a estas extensas muestras no normalizadas? He leído [este tópico](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121852/how-to-choose-between-t-test-or-non-parametric-test-e-g-wilcoxon-in-small-sampl), y muchos otros, pero en él debaten la utilización de ambos test para muestras pequeñas.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Varios comentarios:

- **¿Por qué calculas las medianas de cada grupo?** Fíjate que si consideras los datos apareados, el test que estás realizando (*las medianas son menores o iguales en `dist_A` que en `dist_0`*) se puede traducir a que " *las diferencias en `dist_A` y `dist_0` son menores o iguales que 0*.
- Si no entiendo mal, **estás calculando las medianas de forma independiente**. Sin embargo, **el test que aplicas hace referencia a datos apareados**.

Mi consejo es que consideres la nueva variable `Diff <- dist_A - dist_0` y evalúes en ambos ejemplos la media, mediana y dispersión de los datos. Estos valores sí serán verdaderamente informativos más allá de los que habías calculado inicialmente y que se corresponden más a datos de interés para test no apareados.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que los datos son apareados, se podría simplemente hacer un boxplot para ver la distribución, en tu caso `boxplot(df[,1]-df[,2])` se ve que la mediana es casi cero, que la distribución de las diferencias es simétrica y que no hay diferencias anómalas. Además no hay motivos para suponer falta de normalidad en la distribución, en efecto Haciendo `shapiro.test(df[,1]-df[,2])` el p-valor = 0,5576. Y si los datos son normales los test paramétricos son los más potentes. 
 
Con N = 1500 datos el p-valor da cercano a 1 porque el desvío estándar del estimador tiene a cero con raíz de N. Quizás tenga más sentido un test de equivalencia o TOST (Two One Sided T Test). Tu hipótesis nula es que la diferencia observada entre las medias está fuera de un rango +/-Q de tolerancia: |muA - muB| > Q. Rechazando esta hipóteisis concluyes la alternativa, que  (muA - muB) está incluido en el rango (-Q, Q) con una probabilidad no menor a 1-alfa, por ejemplo no menor a 95%.